# Compiling ES6 React code using laravel-mix

Tags: laravel, reactjs, ecmascript-6, laravel-mix

I'm trying to compile React code that is using ES6 using laravel-mix and I am running into issues compiling things like arrow functions which are prevalent in ES6 from my understanding. So I have a webpack.mix.js file of:

```
mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/cross-brand-nav.js', 'public/js/app.js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/FullWidthTabs.js', 'public/js/app.js')
    .version()
    .combine([
        'resources/assets/bower_assets/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'resources/assets/bower_assets/moment/min/moment.min.js',
        'resources/assets/bower_assets/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
        'resources/assets/bower_assets/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js',
        'resources/assets/js/admin.js'
    ], 'public/js/admin.js').version()
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/assets/bower_assets/components-font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss', 'public/css').version()
    .styles([
        'resources/assets/css/FullWidthTabs.css'
    ], 'public/css/pf.css')
    .styles([
        'resources/assets/bower_assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'resources/assets/bower_assets/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css'
        ], 'public/css/admin.css').version();
```

when I try to compile code like:

```
testFunction = () => {

    }
```

I get an error like so:

> compile error Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token
>   (51:17)

This is pointing right at that function. Any extra steps I need to take compile correctly in ES6?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I have seemed to solve my own issue here. First I needed to edit my .babelrc file to

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2016"],
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

obviously installing the babel-plugin-transform-class-properties plugin and babel-preset-es2016, then things seem to compile and work more like I expected.

Comment: in my setup I don't have a babelrc file.  How did you setup react to work with laravel?  @David Jarrin

Comment: @fabricioG I believe I had to add the babelrc value myself.

Answer (score 3):

Arrow functions that are members of a class are not included yet. You need to install [babel-transform-class-properties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties).

Run this command:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
```

And create a `.babelrc` file in the root directory of your project if doesn't exist an add this

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

or if you need to add some options

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-class-properties", { "spec": true }]
  ]
}
```